# How to access the so called "Posts page"

Tags: blog, frontpage, homepage

This might be a dumb question - I'm sorry for that but:
If I decide to alter "Reading Settings" and choose a front page for home I can define a "Static Page" and a "Posts Page".

"Static Page" ain't leaving a question to me since it's what's gonna be grabbed if I click on my Logo. But where will I face this so called "Posts Page"?

I'm feeling confused somehow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen

> "Posts page - Select in the drop-down box the name of the Page that
>   will now contain your Posts. If you do not select a Page here, your
>   Posts will only be accessible via other navigation features such as
>   category, calendar, or archive links. Even if the selected Page is
>   Password protected, visitors will NOT be prompted for a password when
>   viewing the Posts Page. Also, any Template assigned the Page will be
>   ignored and the theme's index.php (or home.php if it exists) will
>   control the display of the posts."